# Instruccion Update con una subconsulta SQL actualiza todas las filas en vez de una unica fila

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

he creado un procedimiento SQL donde inserto una nueva fila con el nombre de usuario, tiempo y fecha solo si no existe, pero si ese usuario ya existe y el tiempo a insertar es menor que el actual actualiza su fila con nuevos valores de tiempo y fecha.
El problema está en el update, ya que actualiza todas las filas, no solo la que coincide con el username. ¿Cual está siendo el problema?

El procedimiento en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
Create procedure insertarPrincipiante
@usuario as nvarchar(20),
@tiempo as int,
@fecha as Date
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT userName FROM rnk_principiante WHERE userName = @usuario)
BEGIN
    UPDATE rnk_principiante
    SET time = @tiempo, date = @fecha
    WHERE @tiempo< (select time from rnk_principiante where userName = @usuario);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO rnk_principiante values (@usuario, @tiempo, @fecha)
END
```

Cuando intento insertar unos datos de un usuario que ya existe (admin ya existe)

```
 exec dbo.insertarPrincipiante 'Admin', 20, '2022-04-17';
```

La condición de que el tiempo a insertar tiene que ser menor que el actual si la reconoce, pero actualiza todos los tiempos y fechas de todas las filas, y yo quiero que actualice únicamente la fila del usuario Admin.

Comment: El `update` tiene un solo filtro que es el de tiempo, deberías agregar un  `and userName = @usuario` o mucho mejor simplificar la consulta: `UPDATE rnk_principiante  SET time = @tiempo, date = @fecha  WHERE @tiempo < time and userName = @usuario`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no lo habia pensado así, pero es cierto que así es mas simple y encima hace lo que quería. Gracias!